# leaflet not loading tiles

Tags: ionic3, leaflet

I am trying to show a leaflet map on my ionic App but it doesn't show anything except the marker I created!
As you can see, there are no requests to leaflet OR mapbox servers (I use mapbox)

[image]

And this is my code:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import leaflet from "leaflet";

@Component({
    templateUrl: "test-map.html"
})
export class TestMap {
    leafletMap: any;

    constructor() {}

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.leafletMap = leaflet.map("leafletmap", {
            center: [28.618072, 51.538088],
            zoom: 18,
            maxZoom: 18
        });

        this.openMap();
    }

    openMap() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.leafletMap.invalidateSize();
        }, 0);

        leaflet.tileLayer(
            "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}" +
                "/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={my-access-token}",
            {
                attribution: "",
                maxZoom: 18,
                id: "mapbox.streets",
                accessToken: "{my-access-token}"
            }
        );

        this.leafletMap.setView(leaflet.latLng(28.618072, 51.538088));

        leaflet.marker([28.618072, 51.538088]).addTo(this.leafletMap);
    }
}
```

As you can see I already tried `invalidateSize`!

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: did you pass the real access token instead of " my-access-token" ? if not check your access token in your mapbox account and try again

Comment: @A.HADDAD absolutely I passed the real one!

Comment: You're not adding the `L.Tilelayer` to the map - i.e. `leaflet.tileLayer(...)` vs `leaflet.tileLayer.addTo(map)`.

Comment: @IvanSanchez worked! please send your comment as an answer to mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @IvanSanchez mentioned in comments, I should add the `tileLayer` to the `map`:

```
leaflet.tileLayer(
            "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}" +
                "/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={my-access-token}",
            {
                attribution: "",
                maxZoom: 18,
                id: "mapbox.streets",
                accessToken: "{my-access-token}"
            }
        ).addTo(this.leafletMap);
```